# Google sheets count occurrences as fractions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Have a column that contains text separated by a ',' and I am trying to work out the fraction of occurrences for each string in the column as detailed below

```
    a,b
    a
    g,g,f
    a
    b
    b,a,f,f
```

Output needed in another column

```
0.5
1
0.33
1
1
0.25
```

Not sure the best approach here is to use a query and SQL do this? I'm sure there is a simple way?

My current thinking 
    =QUERY(IF D3 contains "," (len(D3)-len(SUBSTITUTE(D3,",","")) else 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SPLIT by `,`
- Divide 1 by COUNT of the resulting array

  ```
  =1/COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,","))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starting in D3, try

```
=arrayformula(if(len(D3:D), trunc(1/len(substitute(D3:D, ",",)),2),))
```

and see if that works?
(Change range to suit)